# 1 to 0-1 relationship?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 2 tables:

```
  Member Table:
  Id - Primary key
  Name
  Age
```

Manager Table:

```
 Id,
 MemberId - FK
 Title
```

How I can write a 1 to 0-1 relationship?
1 Member to 0-1 Manager

This is I am getting, why not showing 1--- 0 1
[image]

Comment: You mean like adding a unique constraint to memberid in the manager table?

Comment: @ZLK an `unique constraint` would not allow more than one `NULL` value. If there are Managers without a connected Member this would not work,

Comment: @Alma, are there Managers without a connected Member? Are there Members without a connected Manager? If so, best would be a mapping table with FKs to both tables. With `UNIQUE` constraints you can ensure, that each value (and each combination of values) cannot appear more than once...

Comment: @Shnugo Sure, but it's not clear whether there can be a manager without a member (just that members might not have a manager). If that is the case, then a check constraint would work.

Comment: a Manager has to have a member but Member can be by itself without manager.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create the tables for this relationship you need:

```
CREATE TABLE member(
       Id int,
       Name varchar,
       Age int
       Primary key(Id)
);
CREATE TABLE manager(
       Id int,
       MemberId int,
       Title varchar,
       Primary key(Id),
       Foreign key(MemberId) References member(id)
);
```

Note: When you don't specify anything for the MemberId, this means it can be NULL. This means that there is no MemberId value for some managers.